# How do you compare a list with an integer in an 'if' statement? Python

Tags: python, list, if-statement

```
if list_1 > 20:

    list_1-5
```

I am trying to minus 5 for every index in the list that is over 20. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to build a new list with the changes applied to all values over 20:

```
list_1 = [v - 5 if v > 20 else v for v in list_1]
```

The expression `v - 5 if v > 20 else v` uses a [*conditional expression*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to produce either `v` itself, or `v` minus 5 subtracted if it is greater than 20.

Demo:

```
>>> list_1 = [20, 19, 24, -10, 100]
>>> [v - 5 if v > 20 else v for v in list_1]
[20, 19, 19, -10, 95]
```

You don't really need to test beforehand; a test to see if there are any values over 20 in the list would require a full traverse of the list *anyway*; the list comprehension would produce a copy of the list with no changes made if there are no values over 20.

If you *must* test, use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions); this at least then aborts iteration when one such value is found:

```
if any(v > 20 for v in list_1):
    # there is at least one value in list_1 that is greater than 20
    list_1 = [v - 5 if v > 20 else v for v in list_1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You apply a list comprehension an subtract five from every element for which the condition that it is larger than twenty is true.

```
>>> list_1 = [1, 22, -15, 16, 17]
>>> [x - 5 if x > 20 else x for x in list_1]
[1, 17, -15, 16, 17]
```

This is equivalent to, but a little faster than:

```
>>> list_1 = [1, 22, -15, 16, 17]
>>> result = []
>>> for x in list_1:
...     if x > 20:
...         x -= 5
...     result.append(x)
... 
>>> result
[1, 17, -15, 16, 17]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) loop and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to do this.

```
for i, number in enumerate(list_1):
    if number > 20:
        list_1[i] = number - 5
```

Using list comprehension:

```
list_1 = [i-5 if i > 20 else i for i in list_1]
```

If you want to create a new list:

```
list_2 = []

for number in list_1:
    if number > 20:
        list_2.append(number-5)
    else:
        list_2.append(number)
```